# HTML code in WordPress menu description

Tags: description

I tried to place HTML code in WordPress menu description, it's showing an inline code `<i class="fa fa-cloud"></i>` instead of an icon.

Already tried that one but still not working

```
// Allow HTML descriptions in WordPress Menu
remove_filter( 'nav_menu_description', 'strip_tags' );
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'cus_wp_setup_nav_menu_item' );
function cus_wp_setup_nav_menu_item( $menu_item ) {
    $menu_item->description = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_description',  $menu_item->post_content );
    return $menu_item;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put the below full code and that should work..

```
<?php class Description_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
    {
        $classes     = empty ( $item->classes ) ? array () : (array) $item->classes;

        $class_names = join(
            ' '
        ,   apply_filters(
                'nav_menu_css_class'
            ,   array_filter( $classes ), $item
            )
        );

        ! empty ( $class_names )
            and $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        // Build default menu items
        $output .= "<li id='menu-item-$item->ID' $class_names>";

        $attributes  = '';

        ! empty( $item->attr_title )
            and $attributes .= ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->target )
            and $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->xfn )
            and $attributes .= ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->url )
            and $attributes .= ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"';

        // Build the description (you may need to change the depth to 0, 1, or 2)
        $description = ( ! empty ( $item->description ) and 1 == $depth )
            ? '<span class="nav_desc">'.  $item->description . '</span>' : '';

        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

        $item_output = $args->before
            . "<a $attributes>"
            . $args->link_before
            . $title
            . '</a> '
            . $args->link_after
            . $description
            . $args->after;

        // Since $output is called by reference we don't need to return anything.
        $output .= apply_filters(
            'walker_nav_menu_start_el'
        ,   $item_output
        ,   $item
        ,   $depth
        ,   $args
        );
    }
}

// Allow HTML descriptions in WordPress Menu
remove_filter( 'nav_menu_description', 'strip_tags' );
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'cus_wp_setup_nav_menu_item' );
function cus_wp_setup_nav_menu_item( $menu_item ) {
     $menu_item->description = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_description', $menu_item->post_content );
     return $menu_item;
} ?>
```

and then use this in your template:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'walker' => new Description_Walker )); ?>
```

Comment: already tried that one but it's not working.

Comment: An answer should include an explanation, not just code (actually IMHO the explanation is several times more important than the code). In addition the code seems to advocate an unescaped output which is just a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly solving the HTML issue, but alternatively, you could add the Font Awesome icons to the descriptions through CSS, within the `:before` pseudo element.

Something in the lines of:

```
.description:before {
  content: '\f0c2';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  ...
}
```

If you need a different icon for each item's descriptions, you can either use the `:nth-child(n)` selector, or the IDs of the menu items (e.g. `#menu-item-85 .description`).

Comment: this idea isn't suitable for me